# libsvm training very slow on 100K rows, suggestions?

Tags: svm

I'm trying to run the libsvm-provided wrapper script easy.py on a training set of 100K rows, each row has ~300 features. The feature data is relatively sparse, say only 1/10th are non-zero values.

The script is excruciatingly slow, I'm talking days (or more). I ran the same script on 1% of the data, and it finished in about 20 minutes, with some reasonable looking results, so it looks like the input data / format is correct and there are no obvious issues with it.

I found the documentation for libsvm to be somewhat lacking and not very helpful on practical issues like performance. Their FAQ is silent on these matters:
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html

Has anyone experienced similar issues with SVM training speed? Do you know of more suitable libraries or specific strategies to try out in such cases?

Comment: If the complexity is indeed $O(n^3)$, then you should expect the full dataset to take $10^6 \times 20 \, min \approx$ 40 years. So it looks like your method is doing not so badly after all.

Comment: I removed the part about n^3 because I'm not sure about that, and you're right, the 20 mins would translate to years in that case. I can't be the first person trying to train SVMs on 100K rows though, right?

Comment: n^3 is wrong. For a general kernel the complexity is in pn^2. For linear kernels it can be sup linear.

Comment: If you are not going to use kernel then switch to **liblinear**. It is amazingly much faster than **libsvm**.

Answer (score 10):

I've seen liblinear runtimes very sensitive to tol; try tol=.1,
and if possible linear not rbf. How many classes do you have ?
How much memory do you have ? Monitor real / virtual with "top" or the like.

Stochastic gradient descent,
[SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/modules/sgd.html)
in scikits.learn is *fast*.
For example, on Mnist handwritten digit data, 10k rows x 768 features,
80 % of the raw data 0, -= mean and /= std:

```
 12 sec  sgd        mnist28 (10000, 784)  tol 0.1  C 1  penalty l2  correct 89.6 %
321 sec  LinearSVC  mnist28 (10000, 784)  tol 0.1  C 1  penalty l2  correct 86.6 %
```

This is with no tuning nor cross-validation; your mileage will vary.

Added: see also [Sofia-ml](http://code.google.com/p/sofia-ml) -- comments anyone ?

And please post what worked / what didn't.